# rest http basic authorization with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, basic-authentication

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new('http://protected/resource', 'user', 'pass')
```

I have seen the above link, when i am serchng for http basic authentication with ruby. But     my question is how to retreive and decode  this user and pass for the login purpose?

Comment: Sorry, what? "Retrieve and decode" the username and password? If you do not have the username and password, you're not supposed to access the protected resource in the first place...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to implement the server end with Rails, http_basic_authenticate_with is what you are looking for. See [ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

Comment: i have passed like this resource = RestClient::Resource.new show_url,:user => user_name, :password => password